# need easy way to create comparator class used for sorting

Tags: java

I was going through the following [Java tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methodreferences.html) which showed how to sort on 'age' for a Person object. In order to do this, you must create a class as follows:

```
class PersonAgeComparator implements Comparator<Person> {
public int compare(Person a, Person b) {
    return a.getBirthday().compareTo(b.getBirthday());
}
}
```

My question is, is there an easy way, such as a wizard which can generate this code for me ? I know there is a wizard which can generate hashcode and equals, but what about a Comparator class used for sorting. This could really be helpful... what if we had to sort on age and name ?I would have no idea how to create that compare method on my own. A wizard could really help here.

Comment: What IDE are you using?

Comment: You've shown 5 lines of code. How often do you need to do this, that you need a wizard for 5 lines of code?

Comment: U must know that how objects compare to each other,something which eclipse cannot

Comment: I'm not sure how a wizard would know how to compare two ints and two Strings at the same time to somehow sort two objects. That sounds like a very application-specific type of sorting that a wizard wouldn't be good at generating anyway.

Comment: Unfortunately, questions asking for tool recommendations are OT for this site.

Comment: You can try using Fastcode Eclipse Plugin(http://www.3pintech.com/products/fast-code/installation.htm). It has something similar to your requirement (http://3pintech.com/products/fast-code/templates.htm#comparatorclass)

Answer (score -1):

No, there is no such wizard. How could the computer know which variables to compare, and most importantly, how their relationships would work?

Another point about comparing names. Different languanges have different collations when it comes to the alphabet, so the ordering of the names might vary by the location! These are all very specific to the problem you are solving, and no general solutions exist.

Comment: You can try using Fastcode Eclipse Plugin(3pintech.com/products/fast-code/installation.htm). It has something similar to above requirement (3pintech.com/products/fast-code/templates.htm#comparatorclass)

Comment: There's plenty generators built into IDEs that do this or similar tasks. The hell it's what building software is about: automating a task...